# how do i create a program to filter out lower case and upper case letters from a string?

Tags: java

I want to write a code to filter out the lower case and upper case letters separately and the number of characters of each kind must be displayed.please help guys

Comment: What did you try already?

Comment: Even if you had tried anything. Your problem is unclear, can you give an example?How do you want it displayed? How do you want to input the string? What exactly do you mean by filtering out?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You can accept the answer if the logic is helpful to you.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**: Traverse the `String` and you can check whether the letter is upper case of lower case as following:

```
Character.isUpperCase(str.charAt(i));  //returns true if char is upper case
```

and

```
Character.isLowerCase(str.charAt(i)); //returns true if char is lower case
```

Where is `str` is your string and `i` is variable used for traversing the string. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Well i don't have too much knowledge in java but i can give a solution in C++. Maybe it help you to implement in Java

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  std::string s1;
  std::vector< pair<char,int> > uppercase;
  std::vector< pair<char,int> > lowercase;
  std::vector< pair<char,int> >::iterator it;
  getline(cin,s1);
  int arr[255]={0};

  for(int i=0;i<s1.size();i++)
  {
        arr[s1[i]]++;
  }

  for(int i=0;i<s1.size();i++)
  {
        if(int(s1[i])<97)
        {
              uppercase.push_back(make_pair(s1[i],arr[s1[i]]));
        }
        else
        {
               lowercase.push_back(make_pair(s1[i],arr[s1[i]]));
        }
  }

  cout<<"\n\n";

  for(it=uppercase.begin();it!=uppercase.end();it++)
  {
        cout<<it->first<<" "<<it->second<<"\n";
  }
  for(it=lowercase.begin();it!=lowercase.end();it++)
  {
        cout<<it->first<<" "<<it->second<<"\n";
  }
  return 0;
}
```

You can improve it more.

Comment: I thought i gave a solution which can be implement in JAVA.. I just provided something like algo.... And i mentioned before writing the code........... And you can down vote if it annoys you buddy... I was just telling about concept which can be used with different data types available in java

Answer (score 0):

This Code will work, but i think i just did your Homework

```
int i;
String str = "Hello Stackoverflow! WaZZuP";
String lower = "";
String upper = "";
String other = "";

for (i = 0; i < str.length(); i++){
    if (Character.isUpperCase(str.charAt(i))){
        upper += str.charAt(i);
    }else if (Character.isLowerCase(str.charAt(i))){
        lower += str.charAt(i);
    }else{
        other += str.charAt(i);
    }
}

System.out.println("In the String '" + str + "' there are " + upper.length() + " Upper Case, " + lower.length() + " Lower Case and " + other.length() + " Other Characters");
System.out.println("Upper Chars are: '" + upper + "'");
System.out.println("Lower Chars are: '" + lower + "'");
System.out.println("Other Chars are: '" + other + "'");
```

Comment: thanks man I was studying and this was a past paper question.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Test1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "My name is Biraj.";
        String up = "";
        String down = "";
        for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++) {
            if(Character.isUpperCase(s.charAt(i))) {
                up = up+s.charAt(i);
            } else {
                down = down+s.charAt(i);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(up);
        System.out.println(down);
    }

}
```

Comment: you can use basic character matching like C